# How to restart IOS application by coding?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
-(IBAction)restart{
.......
}
```

How can I restart a application when I pressed a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, exit the app and then restart it again, there is no way to accomplish this in the iOS SDK.

Comment: i mean when i start the program it load viewdidload and you see a screen... so i want to return this first screen.

Comment: This would be dependent on the structure of your app.  What you mainly need to do, is redisplay whatever view controller you display first in your app.  How this is accomplished, again, depends on the structure of your app.

Comment: for example i have one screen and im clicking some buttons. and when i click these buttons their titles are changing.
i want to go begining with a button. ( there is no titles and colors just first screen)